# Nginx custom configuration

Tags: nginx

I need my NGINX configuration to do some unique things based on the URL.

If the URL is:

mydomain.com/blog OR mydomain.com/blog/

I need NGINX to serve up a ghost blog on port 2368 I have done this by:

```
location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:2368;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

If the URL is:

mydomain.com/some-article-title

I need NGINX to direct to some-article-title.html. I have done this by:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
}
```

FIRST QUESTION: I would also like this to work if the url is mydomain.com/some-article-title/ OR if the case is different such as mydomain.com/Some-article-Title.  How can I do this in NGINX?

SECOND QUESTION: I also need NGINX to redirect to a specific subdomain if there is no matching HTML file i.e. If the URL is mydomain.com/jimsmith and there is no HTML file jimsmith.html I need NGINX to take the user to jimsmith.mydomain.com  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

`location /blog/` won't match requests for `/blog`, but `location /blog` will.

[`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files)... try files. Thus, if your request contains a trailing slash, nginx will search for a directory (files ending with `/` are directories only on any filesystem).

If you wish nginx to search for a file when a requests contains a trailing slash, you will need to `rewrite` the request to its pre-trailing-slash form. Note that directories won't be accessible anymore... so the most generic form showed below is far from being recommended. The trailing slash kind of rewrite is discouraged at all in any form anyway...

```
location ~* ^(?<article>/[^/]+)/$ {
    return 302 $scheme://$host$article;
}
```

You cannot have several files having the same name with letters capitalized or not in the filesystem, such as `some-article-title` and `Some-article-Title`, so a search for either name will always succeed with the existing file.

If you want to redirect files not matched by `try_files` first parameters, the last on can be used as a fallback to a named location, where you can issue a redirect (see [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) documentation).

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html @notexisting;
}

location @notexisting {
    rewrite ^/(?<subdomain>.*)$ $scheme://$subdomain.mydomain.com;
}
```